# failed to connect xbee

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i run the following command i got "Failed to connect to the XBee"

command..."rosrun rosserial_xbee setup_xbee.py /dev/ttyUSB0 0"

i am using ros-hydro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146806/failed-to-connect-xbee./) by [pavanpatel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5686/pavanpatel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) on 2014-04-01**:
A little more context information will go a long way in helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you connect to the xbee using X-CTU?  Also, since the coordinator needs an ID of 0, you should use `rosrun rosserial_xbee setup_xbee.py -C /dev/ttyUSB0 0`

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2